# storyboard: add a new scene after embedding other scene in navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have some scenes set up and already embedded them in the navigation stack (see pic).

[image]

If I now duplicate the lower right segue, it doesn't have the navigation bar (see pic below). I can set the top bar from "inferred" to "navigation bar", but that won't put it on the existing navigation stack (e.g. no back button etc.).

How can I get the new ViewController into the existing navigation stack?

Lots of thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know what order you did this in, but i find that if i duplicate the View Controller, and then just add a new segue from what you have as the Login Table View Controller to the duplicated view controller, the duplicated view controller will pick up the navigation bar and be part of the set of viewControllers .

Comment: Unfortunately not here. Maybe because the scenes are connected to the lower table-section? Is there a way to deactivate the existing navigation controller (maybe reactivating it will take care of the new view controller)

Comment: it sounds like you've already tried deleting the offending segue in the storyboard, and then re-connecting it?  if not, try that.  (i.e. click on it in the storyboard, and just hit Delete, i think)

Comment: Thanks John, that led me to the solution: I deleted the navigation controller and re-embedded the login szene: viola, all is good now. Thanks!